# ionic landscape view only for specific users

Tags: ionic-framework, orientation, ionic2

i'm developing an hybrid app with ionic 2 and my problem is that i would set the app orientation like `portrait` but i need to change it after the login for specific users.

I've tried to search on the web but i haven't found anything that can help me.

These are my system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0
OS:
Node Version: v6.5.0
```

Is it possible to do with ionic?

Can someone help me?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Use this cordova plugin cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

And after login for user , lock orientation using this

```
screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
```

Thanks